# Setting the scoring method for hyperopt-sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameters, hyperopt

Is there a way to define the scoring method when using hyperopt-sklearn for classifiers ?

By default, it seems to be the model.score method of sklearn, so accuracy for classifiers.
But for some problems (eg : imbalanced classes), accuracy is not the best metric…

Answer (score 1):

`HyperoptEstimator` takes an optional loss function argument that defaults to accuracy, see here:

https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt-sklearn/blob/master/hpsklearn/estimator.py#L477-L482

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a working exemple using a custom loss function ?